# updated constraints in traitCollectionDidChange have no effect

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, constraints

With my autolayout, I am trying to implement a special case for the smallest screens, when my icons need to be smaller.  I am changing the constraint for the icons in traitCollectionDidChange().  However, the change has no effect.  I've tried adding SetNeedsLayout, SetNeedsDisplay, UpdateConstraints, etc, and nothing works.

If I change these constraints when the view is initialized, then the change works -- but that doesn't help me when the user rotates the device and I need the change to happen again.  However, it's interesting to note that traitCollectionDidChange() is called at the launch of the program, but if I make the constraint changes within that function, they don't work. They only work if I set the new constraints in the init() function of the view.

It could be that this function is called AFTER the constraints are used, except Apple tells us to use this function for just this purpose, to change layouts etc when rotating.  I don't want to use WillTransitionToSize because only the ViewController is called with that function, not views.  But I will probably try that next.

traitCollectionDidChange() is definitely being called, at startup and when I rotate.  It's just that my changes don't do anything.  Any ideas?

Any ideas?

```
override func traitCollectionDidChange(_ previousTraitCollection: UITraitCollection?) {

    super.traitCollectionDidChange(previousTraitCollection)

    // smaller icon constraints for iPhone 5/SE

    if let constraint = (self.imageView!.constraints.filter{$0.firstAttribute == .width}.first) {
        print("cwide \(constraint.constant)")
        if UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width <= 320 {
            constraint.constant = 20.0
            self.radius = 4

        }
        else {
            constraint.constant = 32.0
            self.radius = 8
        }

    }

    self.updateConstraints()
}
```

Comment: Is this in a subclass of `UIView` or `UIViewController`? If it's in a controller that last call needs to call `self.view` rather than `self`. You can also try calling `layoutIfNeeded()` on the view, I have had very good luck with that method.

Comment: It's a UIView subclass.  I just tried adding layoutIfNeeded() and it didn't help unfortunately...

Comment: So I ran into an issue where custom fonts didn't work unless I waited a little less than a second before setting them. It was as though something else was setting the font. Maybe the same thing is happening here?? If you extract all your code into another method and fire it 1-2 seconds laterite might work. Then you can narrow down the time frame to the smallest value or fire it multiple times (which is what we ended up doing). It's a pretty obnoxious work around but it might work.

Comment: ugh! it probably is something like that.  I actually just decided to forget about the constraints and changed the size of the subview manually in the custom draw function of its parent's view. That is working, but if it stops then I will give your suggestion a try.

Comment: this doesn't work for adding constraints to tableview cells/headers.  it seems to be called after reloadData stuff.  if i add constraint in a view/cell's init, stuff is fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar feature and i turned out that I had forgotten to *install* the constraints in the Interface Builder.